# Is it possible to automate a workflow in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, editing, post-production

I need to edit a large set of videos through a very specific process. My workflow is pretty simple. Add a Watermark, a specific intro video and apply invert effect on the video.

I'm quite new to Premiere Pro, So I apologize if this is a common thing

Comment: If you want to completely automate it for a large number of files, you should perhaps take a look at ffmpeg.

Comment: I agree with @Florian Claaßen; Premiere Pro is not meant for batch processing, it's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Premiere allegedly supports scripting with ExtendScript, an offshoot of Javascript, but IDK anybody who uses it, and the help forums appear fraught with pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I realized that Premiere Pro was the wrong tool for the job. Thanks to Florian I got started with ffmpeg.

For the sake of any future users who might want something like this, I thought I'd share my solution.

The following Command helps me convert my wmv source file to mp4 with a png watermark in the bottom right corner and the source video negated (colour inverted).

`ffmpeg -i source.wmv -i logo.png -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 -q:a 100 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -filter_complex "[1]format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.8[logo];[0]fps=fps=30, negate=1[flip];[flip][logo]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h)" output_file.mp4`

I also made a gist with the broken down commands for each of my requirements. ffmpeg is blazing fast too!

https://gist.github.com/gigincg/338ec705632ee69cfe72eae73c2bb95f